# Testing whether a variable influences another (independence)

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, multivariate-analysis, independence

I need to test the following:
Is P(Y| X, Z) = P(Y|X)? X, Y and Z are multivariate random variables for which data is available.

X consists of the inputs to a system (say a factory), Y the outputs and Z are a few intermediate variables. My goal is to test if intermediate variables have influence on output, and hopefully quantify it.

What's the best way to proceed?

Adding more details: Please consider the possibility that Z=f(X)+e, i.e., Z is **partly** determined by X. There might be co-linearities.

Comment: It will be better if you give some more details about X,Y and Z. Also information regarding background of the question will be helpful.

Comment: The Hilbert-Schmidt Independence Criterion is a popular non-parametric conditional independence test, see e.g. https://rdrr.io/cran/kpcalg/man/kernelCItest.html

Comment: @rnso added more details. X, Y, Z are just multivariate random variables.

Comment: Why not do regression of `Y ~ X + Z` and check if P values for Z indicate a significant relation? Exact type of regression to be chosen will depend on type of Y data.

Comment: Thanks. The assumptions of regression are quite restrictive, starting with the need to have a parametric curve and also lack of co-linearity, need for transformations and all. Just wanted to know the options. To complicate things further, Z=f(X) + e. I've added this to the post.